# Abrir ejecutable de bash, desde python

Tags: python

Tengo un programa en python, que desde una opción le indico que me abra un ejecutable echo en bash, al darle la opción deseada me abre en la misma terminal el programa con `os.popen('recortar.sh')` , lo que quier es que me abra ese mismo ejecutable en otra terminal.

Porque si abro con os.popen, no me deja seguir usando el programa de python, se bloquea hasta que termine de usar el ejecutable de bash, por eso quiero que sean independientes.

Os dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer, en el ejemplo vemos un menu, que tiene 3 opciones, la 1 abre un ejecutable de PYTHON que es un APP y funciona bien, pero la opcion 2 debe abrir en una tarminal el ejecutable de bash y no logo que lo abra, como puedo hacerlo?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

def opciones():
    print('''
    MENU DE APLICACIONES:
    1- APP Compliance
    2- Recortar
    3- Salir
    ''')
    while True:
        centinela = input("Elige una OPCION ?: ")
        if centinela in ["1", "2", "3"]:
            return centinela
        print("[!] Opcion no valida, reintente\n")

def acciones(centinela):
    if centinela == "1":
        ## EJECUTABLE DE PYTHON, ES UNA APP HECHA EN TKINTER
        os.popen('/home/esy9d7l1/Compliance/Compliance')
    elif centinela == "2":
        ## ES UN SCRIPT HECHO EN BASH, SHELL SCRIPT
        os.popen('/home/esy9d7l1/Compliance/recortar.sh')
    elif centinela == "3":
        print("Adios") 

opt = opciones()
acciones(opt)
```

Comment: Si, tienes un error en la línea 45 de tu código. Revisa bien los limites de tu rebanado de listas.

Comment: Perdona Candi no te entiendo?

Comment: ¿Cómo pretendes una respuesta si no muestras lo que tienes? ¿Tenemos que adivinar qué has hecho? Bueno, línea 45.

Comment: Listo añadido, un ejemplo, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres abrir otra ventana donde se ejecute el comando, una solución es invocar la ejecución de un terminal, pasandole el script que quieres ejecutar.

Si usamos `xterm` como ejemplo

```
xterm -e "./recortar.sh"
```

abre una ventana y ejecuta el script `recortar.sh`.

Nota: hay que dar un path explicito al script; si no, no va a encontrar el ejecutable.

Nota: Puedes usar mate-terminal, gnome-terminal u otro presente en tu sistema.

Con eso, el código principal queda así:

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

os.popen('xterm -e /home/jorge/inter/recortar.sh')
print("fin")
```

**recortar.sh**

Esta aplicación ejecuta una aplicación cualquiera (`xed` estaba a mano). El script no terminará hasta cerrar esa aplicación

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Este es un texto
xed
```

**resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa principal termina, mientras que la ventana de terminal y la otra aplicación siguen abiertas.

Comment: Gracias Candid, con gnome-terminal -e, me ha funcionado perfectamente, mil gracias :) ```os.popen('gnome-terminal -e recortar.sh')```